# Database connections count greater than that set by DBCP maxTotal

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, jdbc-pool, tomcat-dbcp

I am running a java web application using Tomcat (version 8.0.43).

I moved the tomcat-dbcp.jar (which came with Tomcat8.0.43) to `jdk/jre/lib/ext` so that it's available to the jre.

I think that I am using the Tomcat DBCP (as opposed to Apache Commons DBCP) but as I understand from the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Installation), the configuration parameters are the same as for Apache Commons DBCP, which are detailed [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).

Accordingly, I set up the following `Resource` element for the connection pool in `context.xml`:

```
<Resource 
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
auth="Container" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
logAbandoned="false" 
maxTotal="100" 
maxIdle="30" 
maxWaitMillis="10000" 
name="jdbc/[dbName]" 
password="${dbPassword}" 
removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="[dbUrl]autoReconnect=true" 
username="${dbUsername}" 
testWhileIdle="true" 
testOnBorrow="true" 
validationQuery="SELECT 1 AS dbcp_connection_test"/>
```

Lately, I have been getting an error in my logs:

> MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections

So I checked how many connections I have at the time of the error (via Amazon CloudWatch for RDS. Specifically "ConnectionCount") and it can reach as high as 150 connections. How is this possible if I have set my `maxTotal` connections to 100?

I am running my application on multiple instances. Can it be that the `maxTotal` attribute applies to each instance (eg: if I have the Connection Pool defined on 2 instances then my maxTotal = 100 + 100 = 200?)

It's as if the attributes that I set in the `Resource` element are ignored. Can it be that something is wrong with my setup? Am I not using the tomcat DBCP like I assumed?

In addition, if I look further down the StackTrack of the `Exception` that I quoted above, I see that

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection

is called. I'm not sure if this means that I am using a different Connection Pool (`DBCP2`) from the one I assumed I'm using (Tomcat DBCP).

Comment: Which version of tomcat do you use?

Comment: @Selaron Tomcat version 8.0.43 (I updated the question to include this).

Comment: Make sure you account only for "ESTABLISHED" connections only.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Where? In my `Resource` element attributes? Or when I count the number of connections?

Comment: When counting connections.

Comment: I use the mysql query `show processlist` in addition, I use AWS RDS console and it shows the amount of connections the instance is using.
Also, I know that it is active connections because my connection pool is throwing errors (it doesn't have any available connections).

Comment: It turns out that you are missing the [factory](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JNDI_Factory_and_Type) required property on your pool definition.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thanks! But do you think this could be the cause for seeing a high connection count? I have been running the connection pool with these settings for months. The spike only started happening about a day ago. You'll notice also that the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) for Tomcat 8 don't have a `maxTotal` attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190646/discussion-between-theyuv-and-luis-munoz).

Comment: I was wrong, the amount of connections still surpass the `maxTotal` figure (even when it's summed across all instances)

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be that the maxTotal attribute applies to each instance (eg: if I have the Connection Pool defined on 2 instances then my maxTotal = 100 + 100 = 200?)

That's correct since you have defined your `<Resource>` inside the `context.xml` file.
Add your resource inside the `server.xml` to make it available to all contexts and make sure you remove it from all context.xml files. Make note of the `global` attribute not present on your configuration

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource
        global="jdbc/[dbName]"

        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
        logAbandoned="false" 
        maxTotal="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWaitMillis="10000" 
        name="jdbc/[dbName]" 
        password="${dbPassword}" 
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="[dbUrl]autoReconnect=true" 
        username="${dbUsername}" 
        testWhileIdle="true" 
        testOnBorrow="true" 
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 AS dbcp_connection_test"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

To keep an eye on:

- `testOnBorrow="true"` causes a performance penalty that is not always worth it.
- `testWhileIdle="true"` is related to `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` which is 5 seconds by default. Default value could be a too short period in some cases.
- Verify AWS RDS quota is [not exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34329857/2834978).

Comment: 1) The number of connection still climbed higher than the sum of `MaxTotal`'s for all instances. 2) I am not familiar with the `global` attribute, can you provide a link to documentation where that attribute is described?

Comment: 1) check the source IP of the connection to make sure all come from your app. I suggest to count ESTABLISHED connections at the app host and compare. 2) [GloblaNamingResources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/globalresources.html)